# Delegating object destruction

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I've found this class definition (`T` has to derive from `TBase`), 
`passResponsabilityToBarDestructor` is not the actual name of the 
function, sadly.

```
template<typename T> 
class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(const std::string& aName, Bar& aBar)
   {
      const TBase* myObj = static_cast<const TBase*>(new T);
      NiceNameSpace::passResponsabilityToBarDestructor(aName, myObj, aBar);
   }
   virtual ~Foo() {}
};
```

I'm wondering if it is well designed. 
When I write a class I tend to avoid delegating destruction since I 
don't know if the delegated class (in this case Bar) is going to be modified 
by someone not aware of the fact that `passResponsabilityToBarDestructor` has to call 
a member function of `aBar` saving the pointer `myObj` somewhere and deleting it 
when `myObj` get destroyed.

I would like to know:

1. if this class is well designed
2. if my design efforts (when I cannot use smart pointers I get headaches trying to 
   write classes destroying stuff in the same class constructing it) are a waste of time.

Comment: If `T` derives from `TBase`, no explicit cast is required: `const TBase* myObj = new T;`

Comment: @DyP Thanks! Actually I verified that users of the code uses as T only classes deriving from TBase but maybe the author of the code wanted to be more generic. Who knows...

Comment: If a class is documented to provide a service (an object deletion service in this case), use it. If it's not, don't. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Why exactly can't you use smart pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegation of destruction actually helps in many cases. I have come across code - where the cost of destruction is quite heavy, so the designers don't want to destroy the object during the call flow - instead delegate it to another thread level and delete it in background (ideally when system is not busy). In such cases, the garbage collector (in another thread) destroys the object.

This also sometimes used for quick switch of data (for cases of data refresh) and delete the old data at ease. I think it is a similar concept as in `gc` of Java.

Regarding as to whether this particular design is efficient/useful, may be if you add overall concept, it may help us to add some suggestion. Effectively, I have given some hint on second part of your question. HTH!